# vimtex imap not working

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

I'm having a problem with using imaps with `vimtex` (i.e they don't work).

To test the issue I went to `.vim/plugged/vimtex/test/examples/minimal` and started `vim -u minivimrc`.

Typing `a (which is a AltGr-7 and the "a" key, since I have a Hungarian keyboard) doesn't do anything.

If I manually set this:

```
:imap `a \alpha
```

then typing `a expands to \alpha, so I am really unsure what I am doing wrong. I quite new to vim, so maybe I just totall misunderstood how I should be using it.

**edit**
I didn't know how to capture the output, so I made a screenshot of the output of `` :imap `a ``
[image]

Comment: Is the original mapping backtick-a or à ? In terminal vim, I cant use my alt-backtick-a to insert à, since the terminal doesnt understand it

Comment: Not totally clear from your post... Are you trying to use a mapping `\`a` registered by vimtex and that's not working? If so, with vimtex loaded, can you take a look at what `:imap \`a` says? It should allow you to inspect an existing mapping... I don't think your Hungarian keyboard layout has anything to do it, as long as the AltGr-7 key combination is producing a backtick character, that should be fine...

Comment: it definitely looks as a `a. I mentioned the keyboard, because in `i3` I had some weird stuff going in with shift+3 being my plus sign :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the `` `a `` mapping is using `vimtex#imaps#wrap_math()`, which only expands to the right hand side when typed in a math context. (See [the code in vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/02829dee17a3d70889b5a0151a2f747754a0e2c4/autoload/vimtex/imaps.vim#L119).)

So, this mapping will only expand to `\alpha` if typed in a math context, such as within `$...$`, inside a `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` block, or in a similar context that is considered to be a "math" context.

(vimtex uses the syntax engine to determine what is a "math" context, see [definition of `is_math()`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/02829dee17a3d70889b5a0151a2f747754a0e2c4/autoload/vimtex/imaps.vim#L157). In particular, that means you need to have `syntax enable` to be able to use that, since otherwise it won't recognize the "math" blocks correctly and will never apply the expansion.)

Comment: perfect, thanks!